# Powershell -replace object

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace

I have a powershell object/variable that looks like:

[image]

for each of those "lines" I want to replace the first string of numbers/letters with a new string ie regex `ForEach-Object( { ($_ -replace '^.+',"") })`

but that doesn't seem to work - what am I doing wrong??

UPDATE 1:

Specifically the LINE item in the var:

```
$copypaths | Get-Member



   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

Here's the Line string which I want to operate on so maybe my code needs to be `$_.Line?`

[image]

Comment: that does not look like any PoSh object i have ever seen. what is displaying that text?

Comment: VS code app in debug

Comment: updated main post to include member

Comment: AH! so this is the output of a `Select-String` call. those `matchinfo` objects contain what you want to act on ... the `.Pattern` property, apparently. so you need to act on that.

Comment: Yes, the `.Line` property contains the text that a [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) wraps.

Comment: What's inside `Matches` --> `Match[1]`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
    foreach ($path in $copypath){
        $path.list = ($path.list).replace("old string", "New string")
    }
```

If you are not sure what the old string is going to be but you know how long it is or other characteristics you could perform any number of operations on it not just replace.